# Difficult to point-and-click target with Apple Magic Trackpad?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, tracking, delay, magic-trackpad

My Magic Trackpad is great for most things involving dragging and gestures, but for simple point-and-click use it is starting to get really annoying.

For example, my bank has a numeric code that I need to enter from a visual grid on the screen, by clicking on the six numbers in order.

To do this is quite difficult with the Magic Trackpad.

**Idea 1**: it is because when you start dragging on the touchpad, there is a brief delay before the mouse starts to move.

The delay might be enough to screw up my anticipation of where the cursor is going to go.

**Idea 2**: it may have to do with the cursor acceleration. If I move it a little, the cursor moves a little. If I move it a lot, it goes much faster.

I have tried various settings in the preference pane, and although the cursor does move more or less quickly, it doesn't seem any more or less easy to hit a given target.

As I am writing this post, I tried a brief experiment -- I chose a spot on the page (the bracket in the superuser logo) and tried to move the cursor there in one quick movement.

It's extremely difficult, even though I've been using Macs and touchpads since 1999.

There is something about the behavior of the trackpad that is making it impossible for me to learn how to accurately predict where the cursor will end up.

Does anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nobody has proposed an answer to this question or commented on it.**

I still notice a small lag when I start moving the cursor on the trackpad, which I now assume is just due to the mechanics of the trackpad.

If anyone can find a way to make the Magic Trackpad more reactive or precise, I will be happy to award them the correct answer.